# Taylor series for with an integral

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

I was trying to analyze a large amplitude problem and I got stuck at an equation like this.

$$\int_0^T dt=\sqrt{\frac{l}{2g}}\int_{\theta_{\text{max}}}^{ \theta_0} \frac{d \theta }{ \sqrt{\cos\theta - \cos \theta_{\text{max}}}}$$ 
where everything is constant except the dummy integration variable $t$ and $\theta$.

I went online to find a solution but found none so far.

I thought about an **infinite Taylor series**: Let $y$ be the required function on the right hand side, then $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ will be the known function itself.
$$ y = y(0)+y'(0) + y''(0)\ldots$$
I was able to calculate $y(0)$ as an indefinite integral. But there are limits in my integral. I am not sure if this is how I approach the problem.

It seems (?) that I have to find an approximation to an elliptic integral.

Comment: Have to find an approximation to elliptic integral